# Difference between the 1/2 representation of $SU(2)$ and the (1/2,1) representation of $SU(2)\times SU(2)$?

Tags: quantum-spin, group-theory, group-representations, representation-theory

What's the difference between the $j = 1/2$ representation of $SU(2)$ and the $(j,j')  = ( 1/2 , 1 )$ representation of $SU(2)\times SU(2)$?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147987/2451

Comment: What do you mean *"what's the difference"*? They are representations of different groups, that's what's different!

Comment: For one thing, they have different dimensionalities:

Comment: 2 dimensional for the first, and six dimensional for the second. Also as the previous commenter points out, there is one group and one rotation angle for the first, and 2 different groups with 2 angles for the second. In the linked question I am getting to the source of your confusion, I think.